# Calling an array of strings located on a Property List

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to bring an `ARRAY` of strings, located on a .plist. I'm making a singleton in order to make it easier.
Here is an example of my plist.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Texts</key>
        <array>
            <string>Text number one</string>
            <string>Text number two</string>
            <string>Text number three</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>Texts</key>
        <array>
            <string>Text number one</string>
            <string>Text number two</string>
            <string>Text number three</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

and here is my method to bring the array of strings:

```
- (NSArray*)getStoryTutorialForEnvironmentId:(int)envId andPage:(int)pageNumber{

      NSArray* storyArray = [self.tutorial objectAtIndex:envId];
        NSDictionary* gamingVoicesArray = [storyArray objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
        NSArray *finalArray = [gamingVoicesArray objectForKey:@"Texts"];
        return finalArray;
}
```

the thing is, I'm getting a crash. I don't know how to make my final array in order to return the text array when calling the singletone. What I'm making wrong?

**EDIT:**
CRASH LOG
    -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa49e70

**EDIT 2:**

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ([defaults objectForKey:@"StoryText"] != nil) {
            NSArray* environment_story_temp = [defaults objectForKey:@"MyPlist"];
            self.tutorial = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:environment_story_temp];
        }else{
            NSString* plistPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPlist.plist"];
            if (plistPath != nil) {
                self.tutorial = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
                [defaults setObject:self.tutorial forKey:@"MyPlist"];
                [defaults synchronize];
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please post information on the crash as well as how you're creating your singleton.

Comment: Explain about `self.tutorial` and also about crash.

Comment: Yes, what is self.tutorial and how is it declared?

Comment: Also, how are you loading the plist into an array (`tutorial` ?)?

Comment: You are using `objectAtIndex:` method for a `NSDictionary` object while it use for an array. Still the information is not enough about fetching.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the .plist composition. In the first call: 
    `NSArray *array = [self.tutorial objectAtIndex:envId];`I get all the items of the array, but when I want to get the array of strings, I get crash.

Comment: @Vergmort - You need to search How to fetch plist file in IOS on google. Its simple.

Comment: @TheTiger but if `self.tutorial = [[NSArray alloc] init..]` then it is an array, regardless of how the pointer is declared.

Comment: @TheTiger I'll do it Tiger, thanks! If you know something about it, please guide me :)

Comment: `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];`

Comment: @JustinMeiners Thats correct. It's an array. But I have problems when calling the ´Text array´

Comment: @JustinMeiners - If you declared an `NSArray` and the object which are you assigning to it is `NSDictionary` type then this error will also come.

Comment: @TheTiger Not true, im not saying its a good idea, but assigning an NSArray object to an NSDictionary type, and then calling NSArray methods on it will work just fine. That is the nature of the dynamic language.

Comment: @JustinMeiners It is true. For example if your webresponse is giving data in dictionary format and you are taking it in an array. Same error will occur when you will try to use `objectAtIndex:` for that array.

Comment: @TheTiger you are confusing declarations with actual object creation.

Comment: @JustinMeiners well, now I can get my text arrays. So in my other class, how can I call each text in order to use them on different labels? Is this OK? `NSArray* texts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[StoryTutorialHelper sharedStoryTutorialHelper]getStoryTutorialForEnvironmentId:enviromentId andPage:page]];
        NSDictionary* textsDic = [texts objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithString:[textsDic objectForKey:@"Texts"]];`

Comment: @TheTiger https://gist.github.com/narpas/6186085 This code will work even if it has warnings.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to get objectAtIndex twice as if your data is an array of arrays of dictionaries, while it is actually just an array of dictionaries.

Try changing:

```
  NSArray* storyArray = [self.tutorial objectAtIndex:envId];
  NSDictionary* gamingVoicesArray = [storyArray objectAtIndex:
```

to:

```
  NSDictionary* gamingVoicesArray = [self.tutorial objectAtIndex:pageNumber];
```

Comment: your array is: NSArray* finalArray = [gamingVoicesArray objectForKey: @"Texts"];

Comment: Yes, I just forgot it. Thanks, now I can see my array of strings. Now I am working to make each string a label.